# tensorflow high false-postive rate

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using the object_detection from the tensorflow/models repo. I'm training the Faster R-CNN Resnet101 Model with my own Images. In my models, I only use 2-3 classes to find particular objects on the images.

After about 60k training steps, I get quite good results in finding the searched objects. The only problem is, that my false-positive rate is quite high. When the searched object is in the image, I get a result with 99%, but on about 60% of the results >90% the searched object is not there.

Does anyone has some hints, how I can reduce the false-positive rate? Is there a way in the used model to give the training specific false-positive examples?

Comment: This is a really broad question, and SO is perhaps not the best place to ask such a question. Have you tried to search and/or ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Can you set up a threshold for the output of your models? (i.e do your models return '0','1' or a probability?) If you get the probability, you can just set up a higher threshold (closer to '1') so less examples are labelled as positive. That way your FPR will go down (at the cost of recall).

Comment: My Models return the probablity to be in the given class. But I think the problem is my training set. I'm just using up to 50 Images per class and also tensorboard just gives me an accuracy of about 40% per class.